# Get parent method parent arguments in Java 8 Nashorn script js

Tags: java-8, nashorn

All

How to get the parent method arguments by using Java 8 Nashorn script js

```
 function callme(message){
    print(arguments.callee.caller.arguments);
}

function callernn(){
    callme("Hello");
}

callernn();
```

Comment: Has the fact that you are running this in Nashorn have any relevance or is this a pure JavaScript question?

Comment: I am trying to run this on Nashorn engine to get the parent method arguments. but it is giving undefined

Answer (score 1):

No. Nashorn does not support Function.caller and arguments.caller properties.

Note that regardless of JavaScript/ECMAScript implementation used  Function.caller and arguments.caller are non-standard/obsolete.

See also:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/caller